# Uninitialized constant error: Can't get this has_many :through correct

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, model-associations, nameerror

I have been around and around with this. Have seen similar questions here but it seems I have an extra complicating factor; what worked for them doesn't work for me.

I have models and tables for User, Group, GroupMember. A group is owned by a user, but each group can have an arbitrary number of group members, i.e., other users. Here are my associations:

In User,

```
has_many :groups
```

In Group,

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :group_members 
has_many :members, :class_name => "User", :through=>:group_members
```

In GroupMember,

```
belongs_to :member, :class_name=>"User"  
belongs_to :group
```

To get at the members of a group, then, in groups_controller.rb I do this:

```
@groupmembers = @group.group_members.all
```

However, that generates the following error:

```
NameError in GroupsController#show 
uninitialized constant Group::GroupMember
```

Like I say, I have been around and around with this... where have I gone wrong? Thanks in advance for looking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this working on my own. The part I was missing was in the User class; since User is the underlying class of Member, I needed this:

`belongs_to :groupmember, :foreign_key=>"member_id"`

Once that was in place, Rails was able to find everything as it should, e.g,

`Group.find(1).members` now finds all users who belong to the group with an ID of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a model called GroupMembers (which you should given this is a has_many through association), your non-through association should look like this on both the Group and Member models:

has_many :group_members, :class_name => "GroupMembers"

For some reason rails isn't pluralizing the second model in the association, so just do it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Unfortunately, it still raises the same error after I tried your suggestion. Some salient points: (1) I don't have a Member model; it's actually an alias of User. (2) My through association model is named GroupMember without the plural s at the end... I altered your suggestion to use GroupMember instead of GroupMembers. Still no joy.

Comment: For now I have been able to work around this by doing the following in my Group#show action, where I want an instance of all members in a group: '@groupmembers = Group.find_by_sql("select * from groups g join group_members gm on gm.group_id = g.id join users u on u.id = gm.member_id where g.id = #{@group.id}")'

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it can also be as simple as the `belongs_to :model` needs to be singular instead of plural.  I made this mistake on my relationship today.